# apscheduler python script stop in every couple of hours itself

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using a scheduler using python apscheduler.scheduler, and in my project, there are 300 jobs running.

As I have 300 tasks to run,I increased the number of threads

```
//scheduler.py
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(300),   # max threads: 300
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(70)  # max processes 70
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 4
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults)
scheduler.start()
```

Above configurations work once start this apscheduler script in background but after couple of hours it gets stop itself. I am using nohup to run this service in background

```
nohup python scheduler.py &
```

Can anybody help me out to get the cause of this issue ?

Thanks;

Comment: Have you tried following the debugging instructions in the documentation?

Comment: Yes @AlexGrönholm ,  In my code I added  logging with methods basicConfig({filename='cron.log'}) and getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG). 

I have used try catch every where still it's crassing.

Comment: 300 threads sounds like a lot to be running concurrently. Are you able to produce a standalone script that demonstrates the problem?